# Batchnorms force set to training mode on torch.onnx.export when running stats are None

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, onnx, batch-normalization

As described in [this git issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/75252) (very complete description), I'm trying to load an .onnx model in openvino backend. However, the BatchNorm layers are considered in training mode when setting `track_running_stats=False`.
Here is how I do this before converting my torch model to onnx:

```
model.eval()

for child in model.children():
    if type(child)==nn.BatchNorm2d:
        child.track_running_stats = False
        child.running_mean = None
        child.running_var = None
```

Then, I export the model to onnx :

```
dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 200, 200, requires_grad=True)  
torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, model_path,  export_params=True, opset_version=16, training=torch.onnx.TrainingMode.PRESERVE)
```

Finally, I got this error when loading it in openvino :

```
Error: Check '(node.get_outputs_size() == 1)' failed at src/frontends/onnx/frontend/src/op/batch_norm.cpp:67:
While validating ONNX node '<Node(BatchNormalization): BatchNormalization_10>':
Training mode of BatchNormalization is not supported.
```

As mentioned in the [git issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/75252), I have tried to look at the BatchNorm inputs/outputs :

```
for node in onnx_model.graph.node:
    if any(("BatchNorm" in s or "bn" in s) for s in node.input) or any(("BatchNorm" in s or "bn" in s) for s in node.output):
        print('Node:',node.name)
        print(node)
```

So you can see those nodes are related to BN :

```
Node: ReduceMean_5
input: "onnx::ReduceMean_22"
output: "onnx::BatchNormalization_23"
name: "ReduceMean_5"
op_type: "ReduceMean"
attribute {
  name: "axes"
  ints: 0
  ints: 1
  type: INTS
}
attribute {
  name: "keepdims"
  i: 0
  type: INT
}

Node: ReduceMean_9
input: "onnx::ReduceMean_26"
output: "onnx::BatchNormalization_27"
name: "ReduceMean_9"
op_type: "ReduceMean"
attribute {
  name: "axes"
  ints: 0
  ints: 1
  type: INTS
}
attribute {
  name: "keepdims"
  i: 0
  type: INT
}

Node: BatchNormalization_10
input: "input"
input: "bn1.weight"
input: "bn1.bias"
input: "onnx::BatchNormalization_23"
input: "onnx::BatchNormalization_27"
output: "input.4"
output: "29"
output: "30"
name: "BatchNormalization_10"
op_type: "BatchNormalization"
attribute {
  name: "epsilon"
  f: 9.999999747378752e-06
  type: FLOAT
}
attribute {
  name: "momentum"
  f: 0.8999999761581421
  type: FLOAT
}
attribute {
  name: "training_mode"
  i: 1
  type: INT
}

Node: BatchNormalization_13
input: "input.8"
input: "bn2.0.weight"
input: "bn2.0.bias"
input: "bn2.0.running_mean"
input: "bn2.0.running_var"
output: "input.12"
name: "BatchNormalization_13"
op_type: "BatchNormalization"
attribute {
  name: "epsilon"
  f: 9.999999747378752e-06
  type: FLOAT
}
attribute {
  name: "momentum"
  f: 0.8999999761581421
  type: FLOAT
}
attribute {
  name: "training_mode"
  i: 0
  type: INT
}

Node: ReduceMean_18
input: "onnx::ReduceMean_37"
output: "onnx::BatchNormalization_38"
name: "ReduceMean_18"
op_type: "ReduceMean"
attribute {
  name: "axes"
  ints: 0
  ints: 1
  type: INTS
}
attribute {
  name: "keepdims"
  i: 0
  type: INT
}

Node: ReduceMean_22
input: "onnx::ReduceMean_41"
output: "onnx::BatchNormalization_42"
name: "ReduceMean_22"
op_type: "ReduceMean"
attribute {
  name: "axes"
  ints: 0
  ints: 1
  type: INTS
}
attribute {
  name: "keepdims"
  i: 0
  type: INT
}

Node: BatchNormalization_23
input: "input.16"
input: "bn3.weight"
input: "bn3.bias"
input: "onnx::BatchNormalization_38"
input: "onnx::BatchNormalization_42"
output: "43"
output: "44"
output: "45"
name: "BatchNormalization_23"
op_type: "BatchNormalization"
attribute {
  name: "epsilon"
  f: 9.999999747378752e-06
  type: FLOAT
}
attribute {
  name: "momentum"
  f: 0.8999999761581421
  type: FLOAT
}
attribute {
  name: "training_mode"
  i: 1
  type: INT
}
```

And that you can indeed see that 2/3 BN layers are in training mode = 1 (-> True).
How to deal with it in order for onnx to consider them in eval mode, while keeping the `track_running_stats=False` ?

I'm not very familiar with Onnx and more globally a beginner in DL so I'd enjoy any advices !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally have found a solution based on a suggestion made on the GitHub issue linked in the question.

So, after setting `track_running_stats` to False, the `BatchNormalization` layers are considered in training mode as you can see in the Onnx graph.

I have deleted directly into the graph the unused outputs referred to the `mean` and `var` in the batch normalization layers, then setting manually the layer into eval mode (`training_mode = 0`).
You must delete the unused outputs and not only set the `training_mode` attribute to `0` because otherwise the check will not be passed.

```bash
for node in onnx_model.graph.node:
    if node.op_type == "BatchNormalization":
        for attribute in node.attribute:
            if attribute.name == 'training_mode':
                if attribute.i == 1:
                    node.output.remove(node.output[1])
                    node.output.remove(node.output[1])
                attribute.i = 0
```

After that, I'm able to run inferences correctly and to have the expected results.

Comment: For `opset_version < 14`, you need to slightly change the method as there is no `training_mode` attribute, but the idea is the same